# mysql substr not working like php substring

Tags: sql, mysql

my date format is like

2010-11-15 04:28:31

i want to pick just 2010-11-15 instead of 2010-11-15 04:28:31 ,

using MYSQL query ,

SELECT SUBSTR(my_date,0,6) FROM TBL ,

This query retrieving just empty value ,

How to form substr function in mysql QUERY ,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQL uses 1-based strings, so the first character is 1, while in php the first character is 0.

Better is to use the DATE function to get the date-part only from a date time field. That is, if your field is indeed a date time field, not a (var)char field.

If you want to display your date in a specific format you can also use

```
DATE_FORMAT(my_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Slightly confusing to say "assumes the first character is 1". What you mean is that MySQL uses 1-based indexing, not 0-based indexing that is typically found in C-like languages.

Comment: You're right, I had trouble finding the correct word. I edited the answer. Thanks!